# Result like a group with Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I have a table (MSSQL) with data like:

```
1   AAA 100
2   BBB 101
3   C   100
4   D   100
```

I would like to list itens like:

```
100:
- 1 AAA
- 3 C
- 4 D

101:
- 2 BBB
```

How can I do this? I have done a While inside a While but the result isn't what I am waiting:

```
<%
    Set Group= TarefasConexaoMSSQL.Execute("SELECT DISTINCT GroupName FROM _NewDummy")
    GroupName= Group("GroupName")
    WHILE NOT Group.EOF
%>

<p>
    <a href="#"><% Response.Write Group("GroupName") %></a>
</p>
<%
    Set Itens= TarefasConexaoMSSQL.Execute("SELECT * FROM _NewDummy WHERE GroupName= '"& GroupName &"'")
    One= Itens("One")
    Two= Itens("Two")
%>
    <%
        WHILE NOT Itens.EOF
    %>

    - One: <% Response.Write One %>
    - Two: <% Response.Write Two %>

    <%
        Itens.MOVENEXT
        WEND
    %>
<%
    Group.MOVENEXT
    WEND
%>
```

Thanks for any info on this.

Comment: Where this table stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any nested loop here, just sort by the group name and keep track of the previous value vs. the current value. When the value changes (or first value) show the group name.

Code:

```vbs
<%
Set oRS= TarefasConexaoMSSQL.Execute("SELECT * FROM _NewDummy ORDER BY GroupName ASC")
Dim currentGroupName, previousGroupName
currentGroupName = ""
previousGroupName = ""
Do Until oRS.EOF
    currentGroupName = oRS("GroupName")
    One = oRS("One")
    Two = oRS("Two")
    If currentGroupName<>previousGroupName Then
        Response.Write("<p>")
        Response.Write("<a href="#">" & currentGroupName & "</a>")
        Response.Write("</p>")
    End If
    Response.Write("- One: " & One & ", Two: " & Two & "<br />")
    previousGroupName = currentGroupName
    oRS.MoveNext
Loop
oRS.Close
%>
```